# TDictionary duplicate entry (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, duplicates, tdictionary

I am trying to add following values to

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  md: TDictionary<string, string>;
  s, v: string;
begin
  md := TDictionary<string, string>.Create;
  try
    s := 'orange';
    v := 'fruit';
    md.Add(s, v);

    s := 'orange ';
    v := 'color';
    md.Add(s, v);

    ShowMessage(IntToStr(md.Count));
  finally
    md.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I know this is duplicate but if you look at second orange, you can see a space at the end. I think Delphi trims the value but it shouldn't.

Does anyone know solution of this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: I just test your code and the dictionary doesn't trim the keys, Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Please don't post fake code. Please post real code. Code that compiles. Use the clipboard to achieve this.

Comment: @RRUZ you are right. This one worked fine but i don't know why the real one didn't work. I didn't paste the real one because it reads from a file and it is big code of a record file. Btw, I use XE2

Comment: Is this updated code still the code that works or the 'real' one that didn't work?

Comment: Ok that works very well indeed. I believe there was a mistake. Works like a charm. I will use this for multilanguage (localizing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code shows a message box containing the number 2 on all known versions of Delphi. That is exactly as is expected and the `TDictionary` code most certainly does not trim your keys when comparing for equality.

Comment: +1. Tested. I get the expected `2`, and if I remove the space (which trimming it would do) I get an exception about duplicates not being allowed (as expected).

Comment: Yes worked great! I think I was doing a mistake. I am going to use this to localize my software. Works very fast indeed..!

Comment: Here is why i choosed this method (adding space at the end). I am translating Hour and Hours to Turkish. But bothe of them translated to Saat. To reverse language, i had to add space 'Saat '. This is how i have solved the problem...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you. I didn't know about that :) I am doing it right now.